# Editing hosts file to restrict website on wifi and mobile data

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, root-access, mobile-data, hosts

I have a rooted Samsung Note4 that is running cyanogenmod. I have gone in and edited my hosts file to restrict access to certain websites. However, I have noticed that the restrictions only works when I'm connected to wifi, not when I'm connected to mobile data (lte, 4g, etc). How can I remedy this situation as to block access to a website no matter how I'm connected?